# Why does the density decrease equal the speed gain at Mach 1?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, density, aerodynamics, air

In [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/94632/70478) answer, it says : "At small Mach numbers, changes in speed cause negligible changes in density, but as Mach approaches unity, both are of similar magnitude. With Ma>>1 , changes in density will become dominant. A speed increase is always coupled to a decrease in density."

Why does the density decrease equal the speed gain at Mach 1? Is it just a coincidence or a result of the Mach number? If it's not a coincidence, what makes this happen?

(it says at Mach 1 density changes will become dominant, but the 3rd paragraph of [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/57430/70478) answer might clarify what I mean)

Answer (score 1):

The answer you link derives the equation relating the non dimensionalized change in density to non dimensionalized change in velocity. By this I mean

$$
\frac{\delta \rho}{\rho}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\delta v}{v}
$$

The constant of proportionality is between these two is the negative square of the Mach number (which is itself unitless, as it is the ratio of the velocity to the ratio of the local speed of sound).

Thus, these *unit* changes will be of the same order of magnitude at Mach 1.

I'm not sure if you are looking for some deep and enlightening "philosophical why" as your answer. If you look at the Laplace equation at the top, the speed of sound is proportional to the square root of the pressure over the density. The result involving the square of the Mach number is just a mathematical consequence of that, along with momentum conservation.

Obviously, it is this equation that justifies approximating "low speed" (which means "low Mach number") gas flow as incompressible, even though the fluid itself is compressible, such as air.

If you want a little more intuition, from a Bernoulli's equation perspective (i.e. momentum conservation), increasing/decreasing speed requires decreasing/increasing pressure (opposite directions). From an ideal gas perspective, decreasing/increasing the pressure requires decreasing/increasing the density (same direction). Thus speed and density must be in opposite directions.

While we can ignore those density changes at low speeds, at high speeds (relative to the speed of sound), we cannot. If I remember correctly, in engineering, it is common to call airflow incompressible below 0.3 or 0.35, something like that. Like all things, it depends on the accuracy needed.

EDIT: I think I can add some intuition for you. Start with the equation

$$
\frac{\delta \rho}{\rho} = -\left(Ma\right)^{2}\frac{\delta v}{v}
$$

and rewrite it as:

$$
\frac{\delta \rho}{\rho} = -\left(\frac{v}{a}\right)^{2}\frac{\delta v}{v}
$$

$$
\frac{\delta \rho}{\rho} = -\left(Ma\right)\frac{\delta v}{a}
$$

So you can also nondimensionalize this by looking at the change in gas velocity, normalized to *its speed of sound* (rather than its own velocity), and in this case the proportionality is still the Mach number, but you drop the square.

This form allows the velocity to go to $0$ with no division issues. At such low speeds, the Mach number goes to zero, and so you can see that for a change in velocity (for example, change velocity by 1% the speed of sound) there is almost no change in density (the incompressibility assumption is valid). As The Mach number becomes appreciable, for a change in  velocity we start to see a change in density. As we get to Mach 1, the % change in density is about the same as the % change in velocity.

There are a two ways to look at this. The easiest, in my opinion, if from the energy perspective. Since the kinetic energy goes as the square of the velocity, the amount of compression and expansion seen in velocity changes is not in constant proportion to those changes. Rather, those compressions and expansions grow in proportion to the speed itself, in addition to the size of the change in speed. This is what the above equation says.

The linked derivation did not consider work and energy, but rather momentum. You get the same answer with momentum too (after all, Bernoulli's equation is a statement of both energy and momentum conservation). To wrap your head around the momentum question, realize that a change in velocity always causes the same change in momentum, independent of what that velocity is (we are non relativistic). However, that change in momentum (technically called an impulse) can only originate from two things, either force or time. The larger the velocity gets, the shorter the time gets for the same amount of space, and so the larger a force is needed. Thus there must be a larger pressure differential in order to cause the same change in velocity, and by the ideal gas relation this translates to a larger density differential.

Comment: So if I interpreted that correctly, the speed of sound is 'lowered', so to speak, because of decreasing density from speeding up, until the density changes the same amount as the speed? (If that doesn't make sense, I can clarify a few things)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, but not really. While it is true that the speed of sound is not really constant, and in fact for pressure waves of sufficient intensity the constant speed assumption can diverge from reality, for basic trans and supersonic analyses to first order the speed of sound is treated as constant. Under ideal gas assumptions, it is a function of temperature only. In the linked aviation thread, just think about what $p/\rho$ is under ideal gas assumptions, it is proportional to $T$. The common equation is $a = \sqrt{\gamma RT}$ using their notation, $a$, for the speed.

Comment: See my update after "EDIT" which should give you some more to think about.

Comment: Okay, thanks for doing that. So from what I gathered, it isn’t a direct result from the air exceeding the speed of sound? (“It” being the density changing the same amount as speed) sorry if I’m not picking up on something obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that. Mathematically speaking, it is a direct result. The derivation is at the link you provided above. If you are looking for some intuition, I tried to provide it. It is a matter of momentum conservation and ideal gas laws that the percent change in density to speed has a factor of the Mach number squared. There are some intuitive reasons, as I provided, but the real reason is the mathematical derivation you linked to.

Comment: I think I might’ve worded that wrong, so I’ll try again. Is it a direct result of the air exceeding the speed of sound? Not that it isn’t a result from the air speeding up, but is it directly from the air speed going past Mach 1? Like is Mach 0.9 that much different than Mach 1,  in terms of density?

Comment: You have an equation, so you can integrate it. You can modify the equation to $\delta \rho / \rho = -v\delta v/a^{2}$, and for starters you can assume $a$ is constant to see the first order behavior. You will get $ln(\rho/\rho_{0})=-v^{2}/(2a^{2})$, where $\rho_{0}$ is the density at $v=0$. You can see that there is not some giant change at Mach 1, they are just becoming commensurate.

Comment: Oh okay, so in a way it's kind of a coincidence right? That the density happens to be changing the same amount as the speed at $M = 1$? For other gases besides air, does the density change the same amount as speed does, at it's $M = 1$?

Comment: As all extra parameters have been absorbed into the Mach number (molecular weight, specific heats, etc.) the equation has no other free terms, just delta rho, rho, Ma, delta v, and v. The equation will be good for all ideal gases within the accuracy of the ideal approximation, which admittedly is not the same for all gases and at all conditions. I'm not sure I'd call it a coincidence, the equation is what you see. Depending on whether you use the linked version or mine, the proportionality factor is either the Ma squared or Ma.

Comment: Also, think of it this way. Nondimensional numbers usually demarcate the transitions between behaviors. Reynolds is the dominance of viscous or inertial forces, thus predicting laminar or turbulent flow. Prandtl is momentum to thermal diffusivity, determining which type of boundary layer dominates. Biot is heat convection to conduction,  determining whether the temperature field in the object is uniform or not. The Mach number determines several things, but in this case it is the transition from velocity change dominance to density change dominance. They are at (nondimensional) parity for Ma 1